# Движок для web-хостинга изображений

Tags: веб-программирование, файлы, хостинг-изображений

Привет ребята!
Посоветуйте пожалуйста самый простой движок для хостинга изображений. Из пожеланий:

- GPL* лицензия
- Совместимость с nginx/php
- Проект оформленный в GIT
- Очень желательно на PHP (банально скопировать пару страниц и в путь)
- Отсутствие галереи либо возможность это настроить (Потому что это не нужно, нужна только ссылка на скрин который я заливаю)
- Возможность установить при заливке время через которое изображение будет удалено

**Для чего оно мне?** Просто есть очень небольшая контора с параноидальным начальством которое запрещает использовать любые внешние хостинги и сливать туда что-то (Ну типа коммерческая тайна и все дела). Требуется заливать туда банально скрины раб. стола, каких-то служебных страниц в браузере и т.п. ссылки на которые будут участвовать в служебной/приватной переписке.

Comment: Движок уровня "залил - получил ссылку" пишется самостоятельно на коленке. Будут с этим проблемы - задавайте конкретные вопросы, а пока это оффтопик.

Comment: Я не очень сильный php-программист от слова очень, поэтому спросил то, что спросил.

Comment: А это и есть уровень начинающего слабого программиста :)

Comment: Нашёл классный [скрипт](https://github.com/fastpoke/image_uploader) но он для apache, мне не подходит и как его переписать для nginx не знаю, мб понадобится кому.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Скрипт](https://github.com/fstpk/image_uploader): Чтоб заработало для **nginx** достаточно в **index.html** в теге *form* изменить атрибут *name* на *action* и указать там имя *upload.php* . Полный код ниже:

   ```
   <!-- current version: 1.6 -->
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
     <title>Image upload</title>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <meta name="generator" content="cat /dev/urandom > index.html" />
     <link href="css/upload.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
     <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/x-png" />
    </head>
    <body>
     <a href="https://github.com/fastpoke/image_uploader"><img style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; border: 0;" src="forkme_right_gray_6d6d6d.png" alt="Fork me on GitHub"></a
     <div class="layer">
     <form action="upload.php" id="upload"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <div class="title">Select image to upload</div>
       <br>
       <input size="44" id="upload" type="file" name="userfile" value="Select" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif, image/*">
       <br><br>
       <input id="upload" class="button" type="submit" name="upload" value="Go!">
      </form>
     </div>
     <div class="footer">
      <span class="footer_text">develop in <a href="http://fastpoke.org/" target="_blank">fastpoke.org</a></span>
     </div>
    </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. [Собсно готовый пример](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) НО тут не совсем то, что мне нужно было в топике, а именно нет ссылки на файл.

Comment: Ну так добавьте вывод ссылки.

Comment: Я не умею 8D я быдлоадмин всего лишь, но не программист :)

Comment: `echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";` вот эту строку заменить на `echo "<a href=\"/$target_file\">$target_file</a>";` (могут быть детали если имя файла с пробелами и т.д., но это уже другой вопрос)